# Reactjs onClick <MenuItem> passing INT instead of STRING

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

Below given code is using material-ui with reactjs. I am filtering the information of products through this sidebar function. In which there are 2 filers size and color. When we click on Expansion Panel, options will displayed and than we click on desired option (which is not returning the selected color). On the other hand same Expansion Panel is returning the correct selected "size". What i can do so that onClick={colorReducer} function return correct color. Any help will be appreciated

```js
const Sidebar = () => {

  const [size, setSize] = React.useState(0);
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("");


  const sizeReducer = (e) => {
    setSize(e.target.value);          //This is working fine
  };

  const colorReducer = (e) => {
    console.log(color);               //It gives 0 as output, instead of selected color (type string)
    setColor(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.div}>
     
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <InputLabel id="label">Size</InputLabel>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <ListItem>
            <MenuItem value="6" onClick={sizeReducer}>
              6
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="7" onClick={sizeReducer}>
              7
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="8" onClick={sizeReducer}>
              8
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="9" onClick={sizeReducer}>
              9
            </MenuItem>
          </ListItem>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>

      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <InputLabel id="label">Color</InputLabel>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <ListItem>
        {setColors.map((val) => (
          <MenuItem value={val} onClick={colorReducer}>    //This is not returning "0", instead of color
            {val}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </ListItem>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<MenuItem>` renders to `<li>` element. Interestingly, `value` is an allowed attribute for `li` [but it can only take numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attr-value). That's why it works for `setSize` but doesn't for `setColor`.

A proper way to do what you want is not to relegate to DOM but stay in React-land. So, instead of reading from `event.target`, you should provide value in a handler:

```
<MenuItem onClick={() => setColor(val)}>
    {val}
</MenuItem>
```